# How to run timer every x seconds within a loop without stalling the loop?

Tags: python, loops, timer, iteration

```
i = 0
start = datetime.now()
while True:
    myFunction()
    i += 1
    print('Elapsed: ' + str(datetime.now()-start) + ' | Iteration #' + str(i))
```

I would like to print the timer information every 10 seconds instead of at every iteration of the loop, but without actually stalling the loop itself, so that `myFunction()` still does what it needs to do (and the `i` counter increases subsequently) without waiting 10 seconds.

Comment: If it has to be rather precisely 10 seconds you need a separate thread. If not, remember time of last print and check on each iteration if ten seconds elapsed.

Comment: Do you actually want `myFunction` to run multiple times, like you have, or are you hoping to print an elapsed time while the function executes once?

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. And yes, I need my function to keep running multiple times and not stop waiting for the timer. The answer below solves it

Comment: An easy option is an if statement either checking the last time vs now. And when 10 seconds pass, it does it's thing and gets a new time. Or if you know roughly how many passes it takes for 10 seconds. You can do a counter and check using modulus for every x runs. `if i % 13 == 0` for example would run every 13 loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime.timedelta` to check if enough time passed:

```
import datetime

i = 0
start = datetime.datetime.now()
last = start

while True:
    my_function()
    i += 1
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if now - last > datetime.timedelta(seconds=10):
        last = now
        print('Elapsed: ' + str(now-start) + ' | Iteration #' + str(i))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you lots